# Facebook always redirect to Web App's main page - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, facebook

Let's say my web app is hosted at example.com , I can share things to Facebook. Assume that I shared an item from website to FB. In order to view the shared item I'm using `item-share` route. And the shared link looks like this

`https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fitems-share%2F33103%3F32194%26fbclid%3DIwAR2cuJOIoexEaWEB_WCTdwp2PFboKK4LtFjs0KitOo1aSOuTZgldZOKluy8&h=AT1xZEuNGfIvCuwtdXg5jlWIwYpfPLWRFev61_1pUg8MJIeC418YTre4MWARPlV7nkEgUFuLey5M9LEX_Jw1yXbQWrJ73p12c-YnQ3sc0qHbEszLzZTcH5L2OI_-&__tn__=H-R&c[0]=AT1oR6q1GGlnfZywsPSMds8HR7HpegOXjoE7YxdV8sKtw1SFYiCrDLWfqd_rLFAIlgDyzroANS2M34bWvtEl0p75iCMhmgHi6Z1QGsdzi0Dj-qMpZaeRWrFK5FbgqNr1LS7ZtEnbRyWezF0uyEhl2XP29Q`

The problem is when I click that instead of redirect to  route `example.com/items-share` it redirects me to `example.com`. Why is that happening ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an issue share items on Facebook or after sharing items on Facebook?

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya I can share items without problem. Problem occurs after sharing to Facebook

Comment: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{route('blog-info', [$blog['slug']])}}" 
                                           target="_blank" class="text-default-custom"
                                           onclick="window.open(this.href, 'share-facebook', 'left=50,top=50,width=600,height=320,toolbar=0');
                                               return false;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square f-22 mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a> this may be helps.

Comment: You probably need to apply proper URL-encoding to that `u` parameter value you are introducing into the sharer.php URL there.

Comment: I got the exact same issue for one of our websites, which is WordPress application instead of Laravel. Sharing the URL on FB doesn't seem to be a problem, also sharing towards FB seems to work. It's once the URL has been posted/processed by FB that it adds additional  things to the shared URL...